# Exclude null values in map function of Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

I am using `map` to process a list in Python3.6:

```
def calc(num):
    if num > 5:
        return None
    return num * 2


r = map(lambda num: clac(num), range(1, 10))
print(list(r))

# => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, None, None, None, None]
```

The result I expect is: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`.

Of course, I can use `filter` to handle `map` result. But is there a way for `map` to return directly to the result I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`map` cannot directly filter out items. It outputs one item for each item of input. You can use a list comprehension to filter out `None` from your results.

```
r = [x for x in map(calc, range(1,10)) if x is not None]
```

(This only calls `calc` once on each number in the range.)

Aside: there is no need to write `lambda num: calc(num)`. If you want a function that returns the result of `calc`, just use `calc` itself.

Comment: Thanks, relative list comphrenension, filter may be a better solution: `r = filter(lambda r: r is not None, map(lambda num: clac(num), range(1, 10)))`?

Comment: @MartinZhu, Actually, the list comprehension will likely perform better. In general, `filter` + `lambda` / `map` + `lambda` should be avoided in favour of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Not when using `map` itself, but you can change your `map()` call to:

```
r = [calc(num) for num in range(1, 10) if calc(num) is not None]
print(r)  # no need to wrap in list() anymore
```

to get the result you want.

Comment: @spejsy Only is this specific case though. In real-world cases you may not know which `num` produces a `None` response.

Comment: What I want to filter is calc(num), not num.

Comment: thanks, `[calc(num) for num in range(1, 10) if calc(num) is not None]` can work, but the same element in the list will be processed twice. Is there a way to optimize this?