# Is it possible to implement filter function using only map?

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming, map-function

I was wondering whether it is possible to implement `filter` function using only `map` function in Python.
Suppose I have a list `A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and I want to get only even numbers. Applying `filter` function provides me a list of 5 elements but `map` always returns 10 elements no matter what functions I could think.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Please don't suggest to apply `filter` again on the result of `map`. :-)

Comment: what is the bigger picture here? `map()` is for applying a function to each item of an iterable not for filtering data. As you seem to already know you can use `filter()` for that or a comprehension like `[item for item in data if predicate]`

Comment: Beaten to it, but `B = [x for x in A if not x%2]` for example, would be a simple solution for your example problem.

Comment: @DavidBuck I . That is essentially a filter function using list comprehension. I just wanted to know whether map is sufficient to implement all the functions.

Comment: Related: [Exclude null values in map function of Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51189698/7851470)

Comment: No, but you can implement map, filter, etc. in terms of reduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) will only apply a function to all the elements of the list. Thus, the number of elements in the resulting list (or generator) will always be the same as in the original list.

(Technically, you *could* use `map` with a function that uses side-effects to add the even elements to some *other* list and use that list as the result, but this is not how `map` is supposed to be used.)

Comment: (e.g. `even = []; list(map(lambda x: x % 2 == 0 and even.append(x), A)); print(even)`)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah, I really did _not_ want to show that, though...

Comment: One could also combine `map` with e.g. `reduce` to get a "filtered" list without using `filter`, but again, that's not how things should be done.

Comment: a 'pure' `map()` solution... `list(map(lambda x: x if not x % 2 else next(iter([])), sorted(A, key=lambda x: x % 2)))`-- recommended of course ;) (might not work on all python versions...)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Wow, using `StopIteration` to kill the `map`? Not sure whether to upvote that comment or flag as "abusive"! :-D